# Thinktecture IdentityServer V3 Events specs

Tags: events, identityserver3

I did activate the events on our Thinktecture Identityserver v3, but the documentation does not specify what properties I can expect in the returned json, or what there values can represent.

This is the url to the documentation how to enable the events http://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docs/configuration/events.html

Can somebody help me locate the specs please.

Answer (score 0):

It's open source, I think easiest way is to look at the event that you subscribe in github https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/tree/master/source/Core/Events